# How to find out a VMs IP address by using VMWare Workstation? Not ipconfig on VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am running a VM on VMWare Workstation. Host is Win8.1 VM is debian.
How do I find out the IP address of the VM without using the VM?

Means: not entering password into debian and executing ifconfig.
How can I find out the VMs IP address simply by using VMWare?

Comment: Do you have VMware Tools installed on the VM?

Comment: yes, they are installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ipconfig` on your (Windows) host and search for the ip addresses shown under 'VMnet[num]:'.

If your host has sed (e.g. with [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), or [standalone](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)) you can list just the client ipv4(s) with:

```
ipconfig|sed -n '/VMnet/{N;N;N;N;s/.*: //p}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn’t specify any additional requirements, here’s a C# solution using [VMwareTasks](https://github.com/dblock/vmwaretasks), a VIX API wrapper. VIX is what you need to use. I believe the vSphere Client uses the same method to get a guest’s IP addresses, although I don’t know if this implementation handles multiple addresses correctly.

```
// declare a virtual host
using (var virtualHost = new VMWareVirtualHost())
{
    // connect to a local VMWare Workstation virtual host
    virtualHost.ConnectToVMWareWorkstation();
    // open an existing virtual machine
    using (var virtualMachine = virtualHost.Open(@"C:\Virtual Machines\xp\xp.vmx"))
    {
        // power on this virtual machine
        virtualMachine.PowerOn();
        // wait for VMWare Tools
        virtualMachine.WaitForToolsInGuest();
        // login to the virtual machine
        var ipAddress = virtualMachine.GuestVariables["ip"]
    }
}
```

Please not: I haven’t actually tested this, so there may be some inaccuracies.